# Visual Code: can't open file [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, visual-studio

I need help with my project, I get this when I run my code
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3CbS.jpg

and here is my folder, and there is bot.py:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3CbS.jpg

any help will be appreciated, please

Answer (score 0):

You are not in the bot directory.

```
cd bot
```

then run `python -u bot.py`

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but I got another issue for the cogs here what it says in the terminal https://imgur.com/3yCZQfr
and here is the cogs code, https://imgur.com/a/91NZobZ

here are the folders https://imgur.com/a/6uQeJVm

Comment: `os.listdir('../EinsteinBot-master/cogs')` try this instead - you need to specify the relative path to the cogs directory.

Comment: I typed it like what you said and still same issue https://imgur.com/a/90avmYQ
any other solution please?

here is a screenshot of the code btw https://imgur.com/a/Es9F6np

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. `print(os.listdir('../')` can you do this and send me the result.
Because it works on my machine.

Comment: I didnt really understand where to put it so i tried to type it instead of os.listdir('../EinsteinBot-master/cogs'), i did print(os.listdir('../EinsteinBot-master/cogs') still same issue, and I tried to type it in a new line like this `for file in os.listdir('../EinsteinBot-master/cogs'):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        print(os.listdir('../'))
        name = file[:-3]
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}")`
can you give me an example where to exactly type it

Comment: Above the for loop should be fine, we don't want the error to stop the program.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zOnd3Zm 

the result: https://imgur.com/a/NB9qcwd

Comment: This is so bizarre. Can you just move the files inside the bot directory to the EinsteinBot-master directory and change to os.listdir('./cogs') and try that way. If that doesn't work either, start over in a fresh repository, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: it didn't work, I think I should maybe try with another laptop than this one, thank you for your help tho, appreciated